# Set EditText lines and position in Java?

Tags: java, android, xml

Is there a way to set the lines of an `EditText` in `Java`? Example

```
<EditText        
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:lines="5"
    android:gravity="top|left"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:scrollHorizontally="false" 
/>
```

So far I have this

```
EditText et = new EditText(getActivity());
et.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
```

obviously I need still need to set

```
android:lines="5"
android:gravity="top|left"
android:inputType="textMultiLine"
android:scrollHorizontally="false" <-- may not be important, to be decided
```

Setting an Id is not important in this scenario, however making it appear as an `EditText` "Box" or "Area" is. I searched quite a bit for some information on this and found nothing. Either I searched for the wrong terms or this isn't possible. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you are after. But you can set the attributes in Java as follows...

`android:lines="5"` as `setLines(5);`

`android:gravity="top|left"` as `setGravity(Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT)`

`android:inputType="textMultiLine"` as `setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_MULTI_LINE)`

`android:scrollHorizontally="false"` as `setHorizontallyScrolling(false)`

See [**TextView docs**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html)

Comment: thanks man, This is exactly what I was looking for. +1 for the nice code

Comment: You are welcome. All the `java methods` equivalent to the xml attributes are listed in the android docs which I have posted the link to.

Comment: I bookmarked it, I have no idea how I couldn't find that early. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to set the lines of an EditText in Java?

Yes there is. Try [`setLines(int lines)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setLines%28int%29).

Gravity: [`setGravity(int gravity)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setGravity%28int%29)
InputType: [`setRawInputType (int type)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setRawInputType%28int%29)

Comment: How bout the rest of the methods, like inputType and Gravity?